# How to click a button on Enter key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to click the following button on the pressing of the enter key. Note I do not have a text box to associate this with. This button is inside a modal and I would like for the modal to close on click of the OK button.

```html
<div id="missing_fields_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Error!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"><p>Please check all required fields</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" id='missing_fields_ok_button' onkeyup="missing_fields_click" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
function missing_fields_click() {
            // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                // Cancel the default action, if needed
                event.preventDefault();
                // Trigger the button element with a click
                document.getElementById("missing_fields_ok_button").click();
            }
        }
```

I would like for the modal to close/click the OK button when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: You have keyup on a button? Nope!

Comment: I am asking if you have a solution? I do not know how to do it. That is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is you've assigned the keyup event listener to the button, so it will only fire if  the button has focus. Add the keyup event listener to the document itself.

```js
function hideModal() {
  console.log("What ever you do to hide the modal");
}

//Wire up button click
document.getElementById("missing_fields_ok_button").addEventListener("click", hideModal);


//Wire up even litener for keyup
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
console.log("Keyup");
  //Check if modal is visible and key code
  if (document.getElementById("missing_fields_modal").offsetParent !== null && event.keyCode === 13) {
    //Programatically click the button
    document.getElementById("missing_fields_ok_button").click();
  }
})

/********************************************************* 
              JQUERY VERSION
              
//Wire up even litener for keyup
$(document).on("keyup", function(event) {  
  //Check if modal is visible and key code
  if ($("#missing_fields_modal")is(":visible") && event.keyCode === 13) {
    //Programatically click the button
    $("#missing_fields_ok_button").click();
  }
})
              
              
**********************************************************/
```

```html
<div id="missing_fields_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Error!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Please check all required fields</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id='missing_fields_ok_button' class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much it worked! Using `$('#missing_fields_modal').modal('toggle');` instead of  ` $('#missing_fields_modal').modal('show');` done the trick.

Comment: @MAB My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56453102/2813224) is the only one that uses `.modal()` method...you're a little confused...

Comment: I'm not confused... This answer from @Jon P worked just fine using toggle

Comment: @MAB  `.modal()` probably overrode the JS or vice versa. Without a doubt the `.modal()` idea was from my answer as there are no other mention of `.modal()` with the exception of these comments and my answer. My answer takes into account that Bootstrap is loaded so there's actually less code to write. My [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56453102/2813224) is more efficient and takes full advantage of the script you already have running.

Comment: @zer00ne I could have used jQuery here, but native js was simple enough (and is generally more efficient than a framework). There was no mention of Bootstrap anywhere in the question, so I made no assumptions there. The question was about how to click a button programatically from a key event, I addressed that directly, your answer did not actually address that and just called a bootstrap method. If there is a more complex method, already attached to the button, it would be called with my answer, not yours.

Comment: Markup is Bootstrap there's a tag for jQuery and JavaScript. The callback `dismissKey()` delegates the keydown event  and the `.modal()` method closes the modal. The objective is met and clicking a button on a key event to close a modal is pointless. I addressed the question within the OP's real situation. OP cannot always cover every angle of a situation. 1. OP is using BS, 2. OP wants to close a modal by key event, 3. There's no instance that I can think of that there is a need to use a key event to click a button to close a modal especially with a typical BS modal layout (which it is).

Comment: BTW my assumptions were correct OP is using BS otherwise `.modal()` wouldn't work at all. You can answer a question to the letter thereby enlightening the OP on what not to do. Or you can consider that the OP may need a solution that is optimal and the OP is wiser for it. BTW were you going to explain to OP that `.modal()` has nothing to do with your answer or are you going to explain how my answer isn't to the letter of the question?

Comment: @zer00ne OK, the crux of the OPs issue is misunderstanding where to bind the keypress event handler. We both covered that. It is far from inconceivable that the "OK" button has some other functionality attached that simply dismissing with the "X" button does not. While you're assumption regarding BS is correct in this instance, there is nothing unique about the classes BS uses for Modals, so IMO safer not to make assumptions. Basically I'm saying, let it go, you've got nearly 30k rep, will an extra 15 make that much difference to your day?

Comment: @JonP I don't care about the points, what concerned me is that the OP is completely confused and not properly informed. OP has completely fallen victim to the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little fun abstracted example of how to fire a click event on a button when the user hits enter.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("I said don't click me");
})

document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
      const event = new Event("click");
      btn.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">don't click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Key events are usually bound to document. Call the BS [`.modal()` method with option `"hide"`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalhide) when `event.which === 13`.

```js
$(document).on('keydown', dismissKey);

function dismissKey(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#error">Open Modal</button>

<dialog id="error" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <section class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <article class="modal-content">
    
      <header class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Error!</h4>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-body">
        <p>Please check all required fields</p>
      </section>
      <footer class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </footer>
      
    </article>
  </section>
</dialog>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```